# Android - Can a group of activities or a task be removed as soon as I leave it?

Tags: android

Let's say I have a menu that has 3 items which go to activity 1, activity 2 and activity 3 correspondingly.  Activity 1 can navigate to activity 1a, then navigate to activity 1b, etc. In order to save memory, when the user click on menu to go to activity 2, can I destroy all the activities that are related to activity 1?

I have looked at all the intent flags and tasks carefully but I could not find anything to achieve that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) flag.

This keeps your activities from sticking around on the stack after the user has moved on to a new Activity.

Unfortunately, this behavior isn't triggered in exactly the manner you specified. I recommend you not get too complicated with finish()ing activities, because your activities will be killed to reclaim memory if necessary anyway.

Comment: I cannot use no history flag because I want to keep the history stack when I am in activity 1. Such as I want to navigate from Activity 1b to 1a when I hit the back button. But when I am in activity 2, when i hit back button, I DO NOT want to go back to activity 1b. Instead, I want to go to the main screen.

Comment: This can be done with startActivityForResult() and setResult(), but it might be better to just rethink how you want your activities to work. What does the user expect when the back button is pressed?

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how can it be done using startActivityForResult()? I want the user to go back to main screen(where it starts activity 1) when user click the back button in activity 2.

Comment: when you launch activity 2 you also do setResult(POP_ALL) and finish() while you are still in 1b. 1a will get the result and check to see if it is POP_ALL. If it is, it will also finish(). You have to implement all of this yourself because this behavior is non-standard. (POP_ALL is a constant value of your own creation)